# Use Javascript or jQuery to create an array from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assume you have an array:

```
var arrStateCityAll=['CA_Alameda','CA__Pasadena','CA_Sacramento','NY_Albany','NY_Buffalo','NY_Ithaca']
```

Is there an *easy* way using javascript and/or jQuery to filter the arrStateCityAll to get a new array (a subset of arrStateCityAll); something like this:

```
// return's ['CA_Alameda','CA__Pasadena','CA_Sacramento']

var arrStateCityCA=FilterArray('CA',arrStateCityAll);
```

Answer (score 5):

Likely you want to do a regex on each item. You can do this with jQuery's `grep` function.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/

Answer (score 3):

You can use javascript's [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
var arrStateCityAll = ['CA_Alameda','CA__Pasadena','CA_Sacramento','NY_Albany','NY_Buffalo','NY_Ithaca']

var arrStateCityCA = arrStateCityAll.filter( function (element) {
    return element.indexOf("CA_") == 0;
});
```

The mozilla documentation linked to above has a solution for browsers that don't implicitly support filter.

Comment: The page has a solution for that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility

Comment: @user815460 That's why you should use `$.grep` :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [jQuery.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/)

```
var arrStateCityCA = 
   $.grep(arrStateCityAll,function(el,i){return (el.substring(0,2)=='CA')});
```

[Demo at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGgMM/)

To implement you actual FilterArray function as shown in your post you could do

```
function FilterArray(state,arr){
    return $.grep(arr,
                  function(el,i) {return (el.substring(0,2)==state)}
    );
}
```

This makes a few assumptions.

1. State is always 2 chars.
2. State is always the first 2 chars.

And of course remember case-sensitivity (this function *is* case sensitive) ie `'CA'` not equal to `'Ca'`.

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
var arrStateCityCA = [];
for (var i = 0;i<arrStateCityAll.length;i++){
    if (arrStateCityAll[i].substr(0,2) == 'CA'){
        arrStateCityCA.push(arrStateCityAll[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are going to have an undescore between your state and city name, you can split on the underscore and test against the first array value

```
function getSubSetByState(set,state) {

    var result = [];
    for(var i=0,l=set.length;i<l;++i) {
        if(set[i].split('_')[0] === state) {
            result.push(set[i]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Use if by giving it the set of places, and then the state you are searching for.